# How to perform an ifelse statement in R with a length greater than one?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm working on a dataset and I need to find all even and odd records of 4 variables. I have SAS code where this has been done, but the if else statements seem more straightforward to me in SAS than in R. I'm looking for outcome where the variable even is coded as one if the records are even and 0 if they are odd. The SAS code is:

```
data even;
  set Validation;
  if mod(MNTHLY_ED_VISITS,2)=0 or mod(FIRE_RLTD_ED_VISITS,2)=0 or mod(NON_FIRE_RLTD_ED_VISITS,2)=0 or mod(UNKN_ED_VISITS,2)=0 then even=1;
  else even=0;
run;

proc freq data=even;
   tables even;
run;
```

In R I've been trying nested ifelse statements thinking this would work. The code is:

```
even <- ifelse(mod(ED_CO$MNTHLY_ED_VISITS,2)==0, ifelse(mod(ED_CO$FIRE_RLTD_ED_VISITS,2)==0, ifelse(mod(ED_CO$NON_FIRE_RLTD_ED_VISITS,2)==0, ifelse(mod(ED_CO$UNKN_ED_VISITS)==0))),1,0)
```

This gave me the error "Error in ifelse(mod(ED_CO$MNTHLY_ED_VISITS,2)==0, ifelse(mod(ED_CO$FIRE_RLTD_ED_VISITS, : unused arguement (0).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ifelse` takes 3 arguments but you've given the first `ifelse` 4 arguments. The 4th one, 0, is unused, which causes the error. It's understandable that you missed this, since nested `ifelse` calls are hard to read. You can avoid nested `ifelse` by using `dplyr::case_when` or `data.table::fcase` (this would be like `case when` in SAS `proc sql`)

Comment: Yes I think it's just a mistake in your nesting of parentheses

Comment: Thank you. I used the dplyr::case_when option and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use nested ifelse or any additional packages.  You can do this simply in base R using %% and &.

```
even <- 1 - with(ED_CO, 
                 MNTHLY_ED_VISITS %% 2 & 
                 FIRE_RLTD_ED_VISITS %% 2 & 
                 NON_FIRE_RLTD_ED_VISITS %% 2 & 
                 UNKN_ED_VISITS %% 2)
```

This will give a value of 0 if all these fields are odd, or a value of 1 if any are even.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this out and it worked and got me the exact output I was looking for. Thanks for your help.